# Bootstrap jquery loading content on selection

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to build a bootstrap UI for a website, but lacking jquery experience.
Idea is to have a fixed to top navbar with selector and load the contents on selection.
Got a question:

How can I load contents of myPage on selection?

```
      <html>
        <body>
          <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="navbar-header"><a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a></div>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
              <form class="form-inline">
                <h1>Select</h1>
                <select class="form-control">
                  <option>One</option>
                  <option>Two</option>
                  <option>Three</option>
                </select>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container">
            <div id="myPage" data-role="page">
              <nav id="myPanel" data-role="panel">...menu...</nav>
              <div id="myHeader" data-role="header">...button...text...</div>
              <div id="myContent" data-role="content">...welcome text...</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075866/jquery-to-navigate-to-page-in-select-option

Comment: Thanks for a link, but his question was to go to an entirely new page, and I want a dynamic load

Comment: you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834462/jquery-script-which-shows-hides-content-based-on-form-select-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I wrong

As I understand, you want an ajax page loading when you change dropdown option? Then I suggest you change your html like this

```
          <form class="form-inline">
            <h1>Select</h1>
            <select class="form-control" id="optpagechange">
              <option value="http://samedomain-url1">One</option>
              <option value="http://samedomain-url2">Two</option>
              <option value="http://samedomain-url3">Three</option>
            </select>
          </form>
```

Then write jquery

```
$(function(){
  $('#optpagechange').change(function(){
     $('#myPage').load($(this).val());
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm. Can you recommend me a tutorial for this type of pages?

Comment: What do you want to know?